# Good Candidates for Deletion

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-questions

Following questions are good candidates for deletion.
Please vote to delete if you agree.

https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7116/how-profitable-is-creating-bitcoins

https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5259/when-will-lloyds-be-paying-a-dividend-again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed – I just deleted those.  Thank you.